# how to automatically show/hide elements with bootstrap nav list

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav list with bootstrap for a mobile site and i can collapse and expand sections if i click the icon twice but when i click on a button the correct section collapses but when i click on a second button both sections stay open. I want the first one to close when i click on the second button.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2219/ .

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top visible-phone" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
                   <div >
                         <ul class="nav ">                          
                              <li class="">
                              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse-filter"><i class="icon-filter"></i></a>
                           </li>
                     <li class="">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse-post"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
                            </li>

                      </ul>
        </div>

          <div class="nav-collapse nav-collapse-filter collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                     <li class="divider"></li>  
                     <li class="nav-header">Filter By</li>                     
                       <li class=""><a href="Filter1">Filter1</a></li>                          
                       <li class=""><a href="Filter1">Filter2</a></li>                            
                       <li class=""><a href="Filter1">Filter3</a></li>                                
                       <li class=""><a href="Filter1">Filter4</a></li>                 
                       <li class=""><a href="Filter1">Filter5</a></li>   
                       <li class=""><a href="Filter1">Filter6</a></li>                                

                </ul>                       
            </div>                                  
            <div class="nav-collapse nav-collapse-post collapse">                        
              <ul class="nav">
                   <li class="divider"></li>
                   <li class="nav-header">Post something</li>
                   <li class=""><a href="Post">Post1</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="Post">Post2</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="Post">Post3</a></li>                         
                   <li class=""><a href="Post">Post4</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="Post">Post5</a></li>                              
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some manual work I think to achieve that behaviour.

```
$("a[data-target='.nav-collapse-post']").click(function () {
    $(".nav-collapse-filter").collapse("hide");
    $(".nav-collapse-post").collapse('toggle');
});

$("a[data-target='.nav-collapse-filter']").click(function () {
    $(".nav-collapse-post").collapse('hide');
    $(".nav-collapse-filter").collapse("toggle");
});
```

And also remove the class `collapse` from `nav-collapse-post` and `nav-collapse-filter` if you don't want a strange behaviour on the first click.

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/ngHnh/

Comment: It seems to be working the way i want it but the first time i click on  either icon nothing happens. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Try to not remove the class `collapse` from the hidden submenus (I'm trying now locally and it's working well, in JSFiddle works uncorrectly).